# How do I stop windows security breaking new video games?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

- I have Windows Defender security on
- One of the features is "protected folder access."
- This feature basically stops programs from accessing folders they are not allowed to access.
- This feature's intent is to stop viruses from opening folders and doing bad stuff.
- *However* in my case this is the 10th time around that the feature has broken a new video game for me.

Examples:

- **Cities Skylines**: Starts, runs, hours later I try to save and can not, lose all progress, close game, see pop up, click allow.
- **Flower**: Starts, runs, get 3 frames per second. Uninstall and mark as broken and give up. Three weeks later I see in Windows Defender log a notification for "Flower" and click allow. Re-install Flower. Try Flower again and it works.
- **Streets of Rage 4**: game does not ever open. dialog box with error message. go to windows defender and click allow.

#### How do I stop windows security breaking new video games?

I’m not sure how to fix this issue.

- I am frustrated and probably will just turn off "protected folder access" because I am tired of this happening over and over and over again.
- If there is a way to whitelist video games before hand that would be great maybe.
- Or if there is a way for the pop up to come above the video game and then I can immediately fix the issue and restart the game (without losing hours of my time. Or having the game fail silently and me never know it was because of "protected folder access")... This would also be great.

Comment: Do not install games in protected folders. That is your issue. In non-protected folders, whitelist the game. Bad practice to use Protected folders for user stuff.

Comment: Your question is horribly confusing. Can you provide screenshots and f the error?

Comment: [Yes, there is an exclusive list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26#:~:text=Add%20an%20exclusion%20to%20Windows%20Security.%201%20Go,all%20subfolders%20within%20the%20...%20%20See%20More.)